# How do I get into recovery mode on ubuntu 14.04 if the option not showing

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, sudo, recovery-mode

I just boot up my laptop then run the `sudo apt-get update` command, but there's an error says:

> [username] is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

so I search the google for solution and it told me to go to the recovery mode on boot menu.

After I got there,the recovery mode option didn't exist. I searched again for another way, then I found some source says change the kernel option with single on linux line on boot menu. Well, I got problem while deleting the kernel option, which one is it?

If the code is:

```
Linux  /vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

which part should I delete?

Anyway, I'm using the ubuntu 14.04; the grub version is 2.2 beta I believe.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the error message is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 1):

If ***recovery mode*** option does not show up in boot menu, highlight boot option ***ubuntu*** in ***grub*** and hit <kbd>E</kbd> on your keyboard.

On the next screen, replace the line

```
Linux /vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

with

```
Linux /vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro recovery nomodeset
```

Then hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to enter recovery mode.