# Freeze after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

When I install Ubuntu, my PC reboot, I have to enter my password, and here is the problem.

After entering my password, everything is normal, but 30 seconds after, EVERYTHING freezes! The keyboard, the mouse, the screen. I don't know why.

I've tried to install a lot of OS based on Linux. And I have the same problem.

I'm a newbie on Linux.

NOTE: Sorry for my english, i'm French.
NOTE2: I have already installed Ubuntu on my other PCs and I don't have this bug. Maybe a hardware problem? Like the graphic card?

Comment: What hardware do you have?

Comment: I have a Packard Bell IMEDIA D4210 FR.
Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2220 @ 2.40GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.4GHz. 
Memory: 3072MB Ram.
Graphic Card: NVIDIA GeForce 7050 / nForce 610i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can boot into recovery mode (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> before loading GRUB for a menu), select a root terminal and try installing NVidia's propriatary driver. Haven't done that this way, but I'll give you some clues what to enter there:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get install nvidia-current
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
update-initramfs -u
```

(you might not need last 2 commands, try them if after reboot still won't work)

You can also try replacing `nvidia-current` with version of driver you want to install. One way to find out what's available is:

```
dpkg --get-selections nvidia-*
```

There's also this, but it gives specific versions, not packages names:

```
apt-cache show nvidia-* | grep Version | more
```

Try it if solution provided by @NonStandardModel won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the graphics driver is to blame try installing properitary drivers. You can try loading the kernel in recovery mode and select Additional Drivers for your graphics card. Look at accepted answer to this question for more details: [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS crashes after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449479/ubuntu-14-04-lts-crashes-after-login)

Comment: How do you load the kernel in recovery mode?

Comment: It is writen in the link in my answer . Hold SHIFT when Ubuntu splash screen appears.

Comment: If doesn't work try looking this http://askubuntu.com/questions/583438/how-do-i-get-into-recovery-mode-on-ubuntu-14-04-if-the-option-not-showing